# create an instance of Bloc by BlocProvider in initState in flutter

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

is it a good practice to initialize and create instance of Bloc in InItState() method in statefulWidget? or not, and why, thank you:

```
LoginBloc loginBloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    loginBloc = BlocProvider.of<LoginBloc>(context);
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: Yes, this is how you do it. Either create a bloc using default constructor, or get it from BlocProvider - both in initState(). Use bloc.close() in dispose() if the bloc was created just for your widget using consturctor.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but please can you clarify what do you mean by this (( if the bloc was created just for your widget using consturctor))?

Comment: Sorry for unclear explanaition. That was just a reminder to close your bloc when its no longer needed, e.g. if its created in initState() and is only used in your widget, then it should be closed when the widget is disposed - so in dispose().

Comment: This is basically what initState() and dispose() are used for. Answering thread question - yes, you should instantiate or get your bloc from provider in initState().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've written is not actually instantiating any object. It's retrieving any instance of `LoginBloc` available from the context provided so It's totally OK to do that. However as far as I know it's OK to even instantiate objects inside `initState` but keep in mind that after creating instance out of `BlocProvider`, you have to deal with closing it too.